# Httpclient asp.net core curl equivalent

Tags: c#, asp.net, solr, asp.net-core, apache-tika

I have an issue with ASP.Net HttpClient POST request.
In fact I want to index documents in Solr using SolrCell. I have used curl like this:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/my_collection/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true' -F "myfile=@example/exampledocs/solr-word.pdf"
```

Unfortunately I was only able to send the file as Multi-part file upload (with HttpClient), this way I need to determine the mime type of the file, which I did but I still got errors for DOCX and PPTX files.

Here is my code:

```
 var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
        requestContent.Add(new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes), "file");
        requestContent.Headers.Remove("Content-Type");
        requestContent.Headers.Add("Content-Type", contentType);
        var response = await client.PostAsync(defaultSolrUri, requestContent);
        return response.Content;
```

Please help.

Comment: What is value of `contentType` variable here?

Comment: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

Comment: File extension : pptx
Mime-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution! No need to pass MultiPartFormData, all you need to do is to pass the file as ByteArrayContent in PostAsyn:

```
string path = "path/to/file";
var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
var response = await client.PostAsync(defaultSolrExtractUri, new ByteArrayContent(fileBytes));
return response.Content;
```